# how to install Kaspersky internet security 20.4 LTS focal fossa

Tags: apt, system-installation, software-installation, update-manager, filemanager

***Please Help*** ,,,,

I'm download this file from server ,, but how it open and work ... (**I'm New in ubuntu** )

**Kaspersky Internet Security.dmg**

Answer (score 0):

that will not work as dmg files are for Mac and not linux. You don't actually need to install an internet security suite when using linux anyway. If you must check files you can use clamav but it is quite bad for false positives. An alternative is to use online filecheckers like kaspersky's own virusdesk.